# How to sort custom objects in NSArray by two time properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

I have object `Item` and it has only two `NSDate` properties.
From those properties only important part for me is time.
If it is possible this doesn't have to be NSDate it can be NSString with just a `@"14:30"` and `@"17:30"`.
I have 10 objects with different times and they are in `NSMutableArray`.
I need to sort all those objects to load them in table.
I have tried something but no luck (actually this code works for one property) with two properties:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
    [components setHour:12];
    NSDate *todayA = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    [components setHour:11];
    NSDate *todayB = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    [components setHour:10];
    NSDate *todayC = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

    Item* i1 = [[Item alloc] init];
    i1.DateTimeA = todayA;
    Item* i2 = [[Item alloc] init];
    i2.DateTimeA = todayB;
    Item* i3 = [[Item alloc] init];
    i3.DateTimeA = todayC;
    [array addObject:i1];
    [array addObject:i2];
    [array addObject:i3];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"DateTimeA" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *orderedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

As I said `Item` `DateTimeA` and `DateTimeB` doesn't have to be `NSDate` they can be only strings but I must be able to sort by those two properties.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to sort only by time no matter which days the dates are from ?

Comment: Yes sir. Only by time. As I said it can be and string with time only.

Comment: If you had bothered to read the NSArray spec you would have seen several other "sortedArrayUsing..." methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
array = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(Item *i1, Item *i2) {

                             NSDateFormatter* df1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                             [df1 setDateFormat:@"d/LLL/yy"]; // <-- make sure it match your date format
                             NSDate* date1 = [df1 dateFromString:i1.DateTimeA];
                             NSDate* date2 = [df1 dateFromString:i2.DateTimeA];
                             return [date2 compare:date1];
                         }];
```

This is just example but you can customize it to match your requirements.
In this example I assume that DateTimeA is always NSString but you should cheek it first and if it's NSDate you can omit formatting bit.

For example:

```
if ([i1.DateTimeA isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]])
    NSDate* date1 = i1.DateTimeA;
if ([i2.DateTimeA isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]])
    NSDate* date2 = i2.DateTimeA;

return [date2 compare:date1];
```

Answer (score 1):

This should the trick

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(Item *i1, Item *i2) {
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HHmmss"];
            NSDate* date1A = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:i1.DateTimeA]];
            NSDate* date2A = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:i2.DateTimeA]];
            NSDate* date1B = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:i1.DateTimeB]];
            NSDate* date2B = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:i2.DateTimeB]];
            switch ([date1A compare:date2A]) {
                case NSOrderedSame:
                    return [date1B compare:date2B];
                    break;

                default:
                    return [date1A compare:date2A];
                    break;
            }
        }];
```

It's not very pretty but it'll do what you want, note that you won't need to this if you have let's say DateTimeA and DateTimeB stored as string in a format like HH:mm or whatever, you'll need only to do:

```
[dateFormatter dateFromString:DateTimeA];
```

One more thing avoid starting your iVars and properties names with an upper case letter that's really confusing.

Hope this helps.